# Subquery into join issue

Tags: mariadb, subquery, orm

I'm trying hard as I can to transform my query to get rid of subqueries. I know its better to not use subqueries, but my first reason to change this query is because my ORM (Doctrine) isn't able to use any join with subquery, it doesn't support it (or CTEs).

Is there a way to get rid of subqueries in this query?

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    e.exception,
    s.name,
    w.url,
    w.web_id,
    w.active,
    w.suspended,
    r.email,
    p.name AS partner,
    p.id AS partnerId,
    contacts.names AS contactNames,
    contacts.tels AS contactTels,
    contacts.emails AS contactEmails
FROM
    service s
        JOIN
    web w ON s.web_id = w.id
        JOIN
    rus r ON w.rus_id = r.id
        JOIN
    partner p ON r.partner_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    exception e ON e.service_id = s.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        p.id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) names,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel) tels,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.email) emails
    FROM
        partner p
    LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.partner_id = p.id
    WHERE
        c.main = 1 OR c.important = 1
    GROUP BY p.id) contacts ON contacts.id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    contact c ON c.partner_id = p.id
```

Tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `partner` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ico` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `partner_idx_active` (`active`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `partnerEntity` (`name`,`ico`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `partner` (`id`, `name`, `ico`, `created`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'partner1', '123',  '2021-05-18 22:27:24',  1);

CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `main` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `important` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_4C62E6389393F8FE` (`partner_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `contactEntity` (`name`,`email`,`tel`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4C62E6389393F8FE` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partner` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `contact` (`id`, `partner_id`, `name`, `email`, `tel`, `created`, `active`, `main`, `important`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'contact1', 'test@test.com',    '123456789',    '2021-05-18 22:28:30',  1,  1,  NULL),
(2, 1,  'contact2', 'test2@test.com',   '123456788',    '2021-05-18 22:28:48',  1,  NULL,   1),
(3, 1,  'contact3', 'test3@test.com',   '123451234',    '2021-05-18 22:29:13',  1,  NULL,   NULL);


CREATE TABLE `rus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_3370C8199393F8FE` (`partner_id`),
  KEY `rus_idx_active` (`active`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `rusEntity` (`email`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_3370C8199393F8FE` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partner` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `rus` (`id`, `partner_id`, `email`, `created`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'test@test.com',    '2021-05-18 22:27:36',  1);

CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `web_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_E19D9AD2FE18474D` (`web_id`),
  KEY `service_idx_active` (`active`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `serviceEntity` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_E19D9AD2FE18474D` FOREIGN KEY (`web_id`) REFERENCES `web` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `service` (`id`, `web_id`, `name`, `created`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'service1', '2021-05-18 22:28:08',  1);

CREATE TABLE `exception` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exception` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_7FC98E6D9393F8FE` (`partner_id`),
  KEY `FK_7FC98E6DED5CA9E6` (`service_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7FC98E6D9393F8FE` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partner` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7FC98E6DED5CA9E6` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `service` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `exception` (`id`, `partner_id`, `exception`, `created`, `service_id`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'test..',   '2021-05-18 22:31:14',  1);

CREATE TABLE `web` (
  `suspended` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rus_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `web_id` int(5) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_15C9385126907186` (`rus_id`),
  KEY `web_idx_active` (`active`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `webEntity` (`url`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_15C9385126907186` FOREIGN KEY (`rus_id`) REFERENCES `rus` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `web` (`suspended`, `id`, `rus_id`, `url`, `web_id`, `created`, `active`) VALUES
(0, 1,  1,  'www.test.com', 01337,  '2021-05-18 22:27:54',  1);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bd8fbb4a3cd028032539539e12073c43)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124409/discussion-between-jakub-stiburek-and-nbk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can just place all the other columns in the `GROUP BY`.** It's more verbose, but it does the job.

- You should place all non-aggregated columns from the `SELECT` into the `GROUP BY` also. Although MariaDB and MySQL allow other columns in the `SELECT`, it is effectively an `ANY(...)` aggregate, and is not deterministic in many cases.
- You need to pre-filter `contact` in the `ON` clause now, do not filter in the `WHERE`
- It's unclear why you have extra `partner` and `contact` lookups, they seems to serve no purpose.

```sql
SELECT 
    s.id,
    e.exception,
    s.name,
    w.url,
    w.web_id,
    w.active,
    w.suspended,
    r.email,
    p.name AS partner,
    p.id AS partnerId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS contactNames,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel) AS contactTels,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.email) AS contactEmails
FROM
    service s
        JOIN
    web w ON s.web_id = w.id
        JOIN
    rus r ON w.rus_id = r.id
        JOIN
    partner p ON r.partner_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    exception e ON e.service_id = s.id
        LEFT JOIN
    contact c ON c.partner_id = p.id AND
        (c.main = 1 OR c.important = 1)
GROUP BY
    s.id,
    e.exception,
    s.name,
    w.url,
    w.web_id,
    w.active,
    w.suspended,
    r.email,
    p.name,
    p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a **View** for your subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW PartnerContact AS

SELECT 
    p.id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.tel) tels,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.email) emails
FROM
    partner p
LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.partner_id = p.id
WHERE
    c.main = 1 OR c.important = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

...and then join to that **View** in your main query:

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    e.exception,
    s.name,
    w.url,
    w.web_id,
    w.active,
    w.suspended,
    r.email,
    p.name AS partner,
    p.id AS partnerId,
    contacts.names AS contactNames,
    contacts.tels AS contactTels,
    contacts.emails AS contactEmails
FROM
    service s
        JOIN
    web w ON s.web_id = w.id
        JOIN
    rus r ON w.rus_id = r.id
        JOIN
    partner p ON r.partner_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    exception e ON e.service_id = s.id
        LEFT JOIN
    PartnerContacts contacts ON contacts.id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN
    contact c ON c.partner_id = p.id
```

Comment: Looks good but Doctrine isn't friend with views sadly..

Comment: @JakubStibůrek It says **Views** are supported in their documentation, for example as a way to work around their [limitations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html): "*You can create **views** for all your problematic tables and column names to avoid the legacy quoting nightmare.*".

Comment: @JakubStibůrek Furthermore here's a [post](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/using-views-with-doctrine.html) on how to use **Views** in Doctrine.

Comment: yeah that's post from 2009.. if I will use command to update schema via cli.. which I do on every deploy it will treat view as a table and there will be a problem made from it

Comment: @JakubStibůrek The first comment I made links directly to Doctrine's documentation, which assumptively is current and states creating **Views** is one way to workaround some of their limitations. It sounds like your command via the CLI might be incorrect if you're unable to use **Views**.

Comment: You posted blog post from 2009. There is nothing said about Views in official doc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8389541/4805218

Comment: @JakubStibůrek [This is the **official** documentation where **Views are mentioned**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html) which I linked in my first comment. The **official** documentation says "*"You can create **views** for all your problematic tables and column names to avoid the legacy quoting nightmare.*"